# Find an equation for the plane through the point which is perpendicular to the vector.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

The point in which the equation must go through is =(−1,−2,6)
The vector is from the origin to point P. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Do yo know the equation for the plane?

Comment: @Ramanujan Thanks. If you mean the general equation for the plane, I believe it's Ax +By +Cz =D or something like that

Comment: In that equation, what is $(A, B, C)$? Hint: You already have a normal vector to the plane and you have a point on the plane.

Answer (score 0):

The desired plane passes through the point $P(-1, -2, 6)$ and has a normal vector $OP=(-1, -2, 6)$, where $O$ is the origin.
Let $A(x, y, z)$ be an arbitrary point on the plane. Then any vector $PA = (x+1, y+2, z-6)$ on the plane must be perpendicular to the normal vector $OP=(-1, -2, 6)$. So inner product of $PA$ and $OP$ must be zero.
$$
<PA, OP> = -1.(x+1) + [-2.(y+2)] + 6.(z-6) = -x -2y +6z -41=0
$$
Hence the equation of the plan is given by
$$
-x -2y +6z = 41
$$